# How to mention the sqlserver database name in spring jpa entity?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have two entities for my spring boot project one is Employees

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employees ",schema = "dbo")
public class Employees {
```

which is in test1 database and another one is Payroll

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Payroll ",schema = "dbo")
    public class Payroll {
```

which is in test2 database, In the application.properties files I have the

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:sqlserver://hostname.com;databaseName=test1
```

here jpa is looking both the table in test1 database since I have given that in spring.datasource.url

I need to know how to make jpa know the Payroll table is available in test2 database

In SQL SERVER Manangement studio we will do this by giving this SQL

```
select * from test2..Payroll
```

by this even if we are in test1 db we can access the table in test2 db

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have two different databases, you should configure two completely different **DataSources** and the tell the Spring JPA to use different DataSources for each **@Entity**. I think the following link would be a great help:

[Spring JPA - Multiple Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by creating a native query, stating my db name, schema name and table name in the query.

This will work like the JPA embedded methods, by returning a list of objects and you can call your getter methods on them to fetch the attributes returned by your repository.

Hope this helps someone.

```
 @Query(
        value = "select * from dbname.schema.table",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employees> fetchAllEmployees();

      @Query(
        value = "select * from test2.schema.Payroll",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<Payroll> fetchAllPayrollData();
```